# std::lower_bound on a given interval range return std::end iterator

Tags: c++

I have a 2D vector which is vector of intervals[**start_i, end_i**] and I need to create groups of these intervals based on disjoint property. This is my implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intervals {
        { 1, 5 }, 
        { 2, 3 }, 
        { 1, 10 }, 
        { 5, 10 }, 
        { 6, 8 }
    };
    std::sort(std::begin(intervals), std::end(intervals));

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups;
    for (const auto& interval : intervals) {
        std::sort(std::begin(groups), std::end(groups));
// for the last interval [6, 8] I was expecting std::lower_bound to return iterator to [1, 5] group element but it's returning std::end iterator
        auto itr = std::lower_bound(std::begin(groups), std::end(groups), interval, [] (const auto& a, const auto& b) {
            return b[0] >= a[0] && b[0] <= a[1];
        });

        if (itr == std::end(groups))
            groups.push_back(interval);
        else {
            auto& ref = *itr;
            if (ref[0] > interval[0])
                ref[0] = interval[0];
            if (ref[1] < interval[1])
                ref[1] = interval[1];
        }
    }

    std::cout << groups.size() << std::endl;
}

/*
Expected Result
group 1: [1, 5], [6, 8]
group 2: [1, 10]
group 3: [2, 3], [5, 10]
*/
```

I was expecting the last interval(6, 8) to get merged with group(1, 5) based on my lower bound condition(std::lower_bound returns iterator to that element where the condition fails) but it's returning an end iterator. Can somebody explain why this is so?

Comment: Are you sure that `std::lower_bound()` preconditions are satisfied?

Comment: @Evg yes and also I am sorting the 2D vector `groups` before calling `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: Two problems. (1) The vector must be sorted with respect to the `lower_bound` predicate, but you sorted it according to the default sort order (lexicographical). (2) Your `lower_bound` predicate is not a valid order. For example, if a=(0,1) and b=(2,3) , then a and b are not equal, less than, or greater than each other.

Comment: @RaymondChen as per your example I am expecting `std::lower_bound` to return `std::end` iterator if 2D vector `groups` contain only [0, 1] and searching for [2, 3].

Comment: Try to use `std::is_partitioned()` with your predicate and you'll see that `std::lower_bound()` preconditions are not met.

Comment: Your expectation is not supported by the standard. The standard requires that the predicate you pass to `std::lower_bound` represent a partition of `groups`. But it doesn't.

Comment: @Evg yes you're correct and 2D vector `groups` is not partitioned according to the predicate. Can you give me some insight how to solve this?

Comment: Your predicate is not suitable for `std::lower_bound`. So you can't use `std::lower_bound`. Use something else, like linear search.

Comment: After the list of intervals is sorted (the lexicographic way), I believe the grouping can be done in a single pass. Just add each interval to an existing group where it would be above the high end of last-added interval; or if no such group exist, make it the first in a new group.